# Issue with AspectJ properties

Tags: java

When i am using maintainJ for reverse engineering with my application i am getting the following error.
Please assist us with fix

---- AspectJ Properties ---
AspectJ Compiler 1.6.11 built on Tuesday Mar 15, 2011 at 15:31:04 GMT
---- Dump Properties ---
Dump file: ajcore.20120507.210546.187.txt
Dump reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
Dump on exception: true
Dump at exit condition: abort
---- Exception Information ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.remap(LazyMethodGen.java:1415)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.addExceptionHandlers(LazyMethodGen.java:1269)
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AspectJ, but you should provide some context in how you are calling the method that throws the exception, otherwise you will most likely not get much help (because we won't be able to figure out what is going wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is similar to the one described on the [MaintainJ blog](http://maintainj.com/blog/?p=36).

Basically, you need to exclude the trouble causing classes from scope. The typical CGLIB exceptions are as below:

```
SEVERE: xxx/yyy/zzz/SampleClassABC$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2eb78e34
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.remap(LazyMethodGen.java:1415)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.addExceptionHandlers(LazyMethodGen.java:1269)
```

You can exclude this class in the aop.xml file as below:

```
<exclude within="xxx.yyy.zzz.SampleClassABC*ByCGLIB*"/>
```

Exclude all the trouble causing classes in a similar manner and restart the server. We are basically excluding the CGLIB generated proxy classes from AspectJ instrumentation.

Comment: Yes Choudary, Now i am able to run my application with Maintainj.
thanks